# Offloading Java process to NVidia DirectCompute

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

Suppose I have a PC with a NVidai DirectCompute capable PCIe Card, on a  Windows 7 machine, running a application will it automatically offload process the CPU cannot handle?

Does a Java application have a potential of being offloaded to the GPU, supposing that the application eats a lot of resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not generally.

Programs must be specifically written to the APIs of DirectCompute, OpenCL, etc., in order to use the GPU. General purpose programs not written to such APIs will not use the GPU.

Comment: So in other words a JVM for DirectCompute must be compiled to be able to harness the GPU

Comment: More specifically, the programmer has to write the program to use the API.